# Laravel + Livewire + 2 AplineJS Select Search not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm just taking my first steps in Livewire and AplineJS and can't figure out the result updates in the component. Select Search. More precisely, the problem occurs when trying to change the values ​​dynamically, using Livewire.

**My blade template:**

```
<x-form wire:submit.prevent="save">
    <x-form.select-search :data="$projects" wire:model="selectedProjects" name="task_project" label="Select Projects" multiple required />
    <x-form.select-search :data="$publicResponsible" wire:model="selectedResponsible" name="task_responsible" label="Select Responsible" multiple required />
    <x-form.submit>Add task</x-form.submit>
</x-form>
```

On initial boot everything is fine. After I select a project (selectProject) Livewire runs the method:

```
 public function updatedSelectedProjects()
    {

        $this->publicResponsible = $this->getResponsible();
        //$this->publicResponsible = array(90 => "TEST");
    }
```

So I assign an array with data to the publicResponsible variable.
The data format is correct; after printing the array, I see the absolutely correct structure.

But my Select Search component does not want to rebuild and gives errors: **key is not defined and index is not defined.**

That is, AlpineJS cannot process the array correctly.

**Alpine Select Search Component:**

```
@props([
    'data' => [],
    'placeholder' => 'Select an option',
    'limit' => 40,
    'label' => '',
    'required' => ''
])


<div
    x-data="AlpineSelect({
        data: {{ json_encode($data) }},
        selected:  @entangle($attributes->wire('model')).live,
        placeholder: '{{ $placeholder }}',
        multiple: {{ isset($attributes['multiple']) ? 'true':'false' }},
        disabled: {{ isset($attributes['disabled']) ? 'true':'false' }},
        limit: {{ $limit }},
    })"
    x-init="init()"
    @click.away="closeSelect()"
    @click.away="closeSelect()"
    @keydown.escape="closeSelect()"
    @keydown.arrow-down.prevent="increaseIndex()"
    @keydown.arrow-up.prevent="decreaseIndex()"
    @keydown.enter="selectOption(Object.keys(options)[currentIndex])"
    {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "w-full"]) }}
>

    <label class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">{{ $label }} @if ($required != '') <span class="error">*</span>@endif</label>
    <div
        class="relative content-center w-full p-1 text-left bg-white border rounded-md sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"
        x-bind:class="{'border-blue-300 ring ring-blue-200 ring-opacity-50':open, 'bg-gray-200 cursor-default':disabled}"
        @click.prevent="toggleSelect()"
    >
        <div id="placeholder">
            <div class="inline-block m-1" x-show="selected.length === 0" x-text="placeholder">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        @isset($attributes['multiple'])
            <div class="flex flex-wrap space-x-1" x-cloak x-show="selected.length > 0">
                <template x-for="(key, index) in selected" :key="index">
                    <div class="text-gray-800 rounded-full truncate bg-blue-300 px-2 py-0.5 my-0.5 flex flex-row items-center">
                        <div class="px-2 truncate" x-text="data[key]"></div>
                        <div x-show="!disabled" x-bind:class="{'cursor-pointer':!disabled}" class="w-4" @click.prevent.stop="deselectOption(index)"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class = 'h-4 fill-current'><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 16.538l-4.592-4.548 4.546-4.587-1.416-1.403-4.545 4.589-4.588-4.543-1.405 1.405 4.593 4.552-4.547 4.592 1.405 1.405 4.555-4.596 4.591 4.55 1.403-1.416z"/></svg></div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="" x-cloak x-show="selected">
                <div class="text-gray-800 py-0.5 my-0.5 flex flex-row items-center">
                    <div class="px-2 truncate" x-text="data[selected]"></div>
                    <div x-show="!disabled" x-bind:class="{'cursor-pointer':!disabled}" class="h-4" @click.prevent.stop="deselectOption()"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class = 'h-4 fill-current'><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 16.538l-4.592-4.548 4.546-4.587-1.416-1.403-4.545 4.589-4.588-4.543-1.405 1.405 4.593 4.552-4.547 4.592 1.405 1.405 4.555-4.596 4.591 4.55 1.403-1.416z"/></svg></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

        <div
            class="mt-0.5 w-full bg-white border-gray-300 rounded-b-md border absolute top-full left-0 z-30"
            x-show="open"
            x-cloak
        >

            <div class="relative z-30 w-full p-2 bg-white">
                <input type="search" x-model="search" x-on:click.prevent.stop="open=true" class="block w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:border-blue-300 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>

            <div x-ref="dropdown" class="relative z-30 p-2 overflow-y-auto max-h-60" >
                <div x-cloak x-show="Object.keys(options).length === 0" x-text="emptyOptionsMessage">Gragr</div>
                <template x-for="(key, index) in Object.keys(options)" :key="index" >
                    @isset($attributes['multiple'])
                    <div
                        class="px-2 py-1"
                        x-bind:class="{'bg-gray-300 text-white hover:none':selected.includes(key), 'hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer':!(selected.includes(key)), 'bg-blue-500 text-white':currentIndex==index}"
                        @click.prevent.stop="selectOption(key)"
                        x-text="Object.values(options)[index]">
                    </div>
                    @else
                    <div
                        class="px-2 py-1"
                        x-bind:class="{'bg-gray-300 text-white hover:none':selected==key, 'hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer':!(selected==key), 'bg-blue-500 text-white':currentIndex==index}"
                        @click.prevent.stop="selectOption(key)"
                        x-text="Object.values(options)[index]">
                    </div>
                    @endisset
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@error($attributes->wire('model')->value)
    <p class="error">{{ $message }}</p>
@enderror

@once
    <script>
        function AlpineSelect(config) {
            return {
                data: config.data ?? [],
                open: false,
                search: '',
                options: {},
                emptyOptionsMessage: 'No results match your search.',
                placeholder: config.placeholder,
                selected: config.selected,
                multiple: config.multiple,
                currentIndex: 0,
                isLoading: false,
                disabled: config.disabled ?? false,
                limit: config.limit ?? 40,

                init: function() {

                    if(this.selected == null ){
                        if(this.multiple)
                            this.selected = []
                        else
                            this.selected = ''
                    }
                    if(!this.data) this.data = {}

                    this.resetOptions()

                    this.$watch('search', ((values) => {
                        if (!this.open || !values) {
                            this.resetOptions()
                            return
                        }
                        this.options = Object.keys(this.data)
                            .filter((key) => this.data[key].toLowerCase().includes(values.toLowerCase()))
                            .slice(0, this.limit)
                            .reduce((options, key) => {
                                options[key] = this.data[key]
                                return options
                            }, {})



                        this.currentIndex=0
                    }))

                },

                resetOptions: function() {
                    this.options = Object.keys(this.data)
                        .slice(0,this.limit)
                        .reduce((options, key) => {
                            options[key] = this.data[key]
                            return options
                        }, {})

                    console.log(this.options);
                },

                closeSelect: function() {
                    this.open = false
                    this.search = ''
                },

                toggleSelect: function() {
                    if(!this.disabled) {
                        if (this.open) {
                            return this.closeSelect()
                        }

                        this.open = true
                    }
                },

                deselectOption: function(index) {
                    if(this.multiple) {
                        this.selected.splice(index, 1)
                    }
                    else {
                        this.selected = ''
                    }

                },

                selectOption: function(value) {
                    if(!this.disabled) {
                        // If multiple push to the array, if not, keep that value and close menu
                        if(this.multiple){
                            // If it's not already in there
                            if (!this.selected.includes(value)) {
                                this.selected.push(value)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            this.selected=value
                            this.closeSelect()
                        }
                    }
                },

                increaseIndex: function() {
                    if(this.currentIndex == Object.keys(this.options).length)
                        this.currentIndex = 0
                    else
                        this.currentIndex++
                },

                decreaseIndex: function() {
                    if(this.currentIndex == 0)
                        this.currentIndex = Object.keys(this.options).length-1
                    else
                        this.currentIndex--;
                },
            }
        }
    </script>

@endonce
```

Thus, the component works fine when the page is initially loaded, but when I update the data array (without breaking its structure), the component does not work as expected.

Comment: Since you are learning, why don't you use Alpine 3?